# How to insert blank line between two texts without creating paragraph?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I want to insert a blank line between two texts, but I don't want to create a paragraph in second texts. First text and Second texts should start in straight line.
For example,

The Moon is in synchronous rotation with Earth, always showing the same face with its near side marked by dark volcanic maria that fill between the bright ancient crustal highlands and the prominent impact craters.

The Moon's gravitational influence produces the ocean tides, body tides, and the slight lengthening of the day.

I tried many commands but I get paragraph in second texts. If I use `\vspace,\bigskip` etc. then I get blank line but not exactly after first text, I get blank line somewhere else. Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do not want to create a new paragraph?

Comment: Welcome! Bit hard to guess what you want. An MWE would help, but also more detail. Do you just mean you don't want the next paragraph to be indented?

Comment: if you want to start a new line, and leave a bit of space between the "broken" line and the start of the next line, insert `\\[<dimen>]`, where `<dimen>` is the amount of space you would like to skip.  (2 or 3pt should be enough to be noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you mean indentation... Try and put `\noindent` in the beginning of every paragraph. For example:

```
\noindent The Moon is in synchronous rotation with Earth, always showing the same face with its near side marked by dark volcanic maria that fill between the bright ancient crustal highlands and the prominent impact craters.

\noindent The Moon's gravitational influence produces the ocean tides, body tides, and the slight lengthening of the day.//
```

There is a more elegant way to solve this by adding this line `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` before the `\begin{document}` and this will reduce indentation for all paragraphs in your document.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I wanted. However I have to put \\ at the end of first line then it works.

Comment: That's to create a paragraph yes.

Comment: @ramanujan -- No!! Do not use `\\ ` to 'start' a new paragraph!

Comment: if I don't use \\ then I don't get a blank line between texts

Comment: @ramanujan Never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph you will get an underfull 10000 warning in the log (which is as bad as is possible to get) and really bad line and page breaking behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The advice in the accepted answer is fine with respect to how one might change the `\parindent`. However, if you want a 'gap' between all paragraphs in general, then you should not be using `\\`. A better choice is to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                           
\usepackage{lipsum} % this is just so we can use the \lipsum command to generate filler text

\begin{document} 

\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

The option `parfill` helps ensure there's a little bit of blank space at the end of the paragraph to help make it clear that the paragraph has ended. This can be helpful when a new paragraph starts at the top of a new page.